# Is the [chemistry-olympiad] tag necessary?

Tags: discussion

[Three questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry-olympiad) were recently asked regarding the chemistry olympiad.  While this is where the questions are coming from is the tag really necessary? If not, should I edit out these tags or is there something that moderators would do with this instead?

I would argue that these tags are not necessary because there probably aren't any experts in the field and there are almost undoubtedly more appropriate tags on a question by question basis.

Comment: I only just today discovered the tag and wondered whether it is necessary too. So, I would support deleting it.

Comment: I would support deleting it, too. They could be merged with [tag:homework] and we could keep [tag:chemistry-olympiad] as a synonym as I am sure this will pop up again.

Comment: I think its also worth noting that only one person has used the tag - presumably because (s)he is just working through the test and asking questions as they come up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed the tag from those questions and replaced it with some hopefully better ones.

[chemistry-olympiad](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry-olympiad) is not a useful tag :)

Comment: In the future should I continue to make meta posts about things like this or just edit it myself? Or should I wait until I have enough rep to edit things without needing them to be reviewed?

Comment: @Dannnno if it's blatantly a bad tag (like this one), go ahead and edit. If it requires discussion, go to meta. You can also ping one of the mods or community members in [chat] for a quick validation.

Comment: Why is it not a useful tag? On Math SE, the [contest math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contest-math) tag has close to 6000 questions. What makes chemistry olympiads different from mathematics olympiads?

Comment: @rodrigo Math.SE is a different site.

Comment: contest questions are fundamentally a meta tag, and it seems like you can get the same effect by just searching "Olympiad"

Comment: I am aware of that. Yet, is olympiad-level chemistry simply too boring to be of interest to anyone not preparing to compete in an olympiad? It seems that olympiad-level mathematics sometimes interests professional mathematicians. How are things different in chemistry? Yes, one can search "olympiad" or "icho", or the interested reader could add the tag (if it existed) to his list of watched tags and find all questions on olympiad-level chemistry in less than a second, whenever he wished.

Comment: @rodrigo it's not too boring. such questions have merit irrespective of their ties to the Olympiad. Saying they shouldn't be tagged as Olympiad is not saying they shouldn't exist, please do not equivocate.

Comment: Overall the SE network has a strong avoidance of meta tags. This is a meta tag.